How can I rederict output to screen and file witout adding delays?
I have an executable producing some output (stdout and stderr). I want to log it in a file and at the same display it in the terminal.
I'm using the following code:
my_executable 2>&1 |
tee my_output.txt

It is working but the output is printed on the screen with a big delay compared to the case where I just run my_executable without redirecting the output also to a file.
It seems tee has an internal queue and doesn't send the output on the screen immediately.
How can I remove the delay? Are there alternatives to tee that don't add the delay?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/how-to-turn-off-stdout-buffering-in-a-pipe

Buffering is an OS feature, not a feature of tee. How to disable buffering is a common FAQ.

In addition to what tripleee said: And don't forget to also turn off  buffering in my_executable.
